# Finding a hamiltonian path with Javascript. How to improve efficiency?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph-theory

I'm trying to solve this kata:

> Given an integer N (<1000), return an array of integers 1..N where the sum of each 2 consecutive numbers is a perfect square. If that's not possible, return `false`.

For example, if `N=15`, the result should be this array: `[9, 7, 2, 14, 11, 5, 4, 12, 13, 3, 6, 10, 15, 1, 8]`. Below `N=14`, there's no answer, so the function should return `false`.

I thought 'how hard can this be?' and it's been long days in the rabbit hole. I've been programming for just a few months and don't have a background of CS so I'll write what I understand so far of the problem trying to use the proper concepts but please feel free to tell me if any expression is not correct.

Apparently, the problem is very similar to a known problem in graph theory called [TSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem). In this case, the vertices are connected if the sum of them is a perfect square. Also, I don't have to look for a cycle, just find one [Hamiltonian Path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem#Algorithms), not all.

I understand that what I'm using is backtracking. I build an object that represents the graph and then try to find the path recursively. This is how I build the object:

```
function buildAdjacentsObject (limit) {
  const potentialSquares = getPotentialSquares(limit)
  const adjacents = {}
  for (let i = 0; i < (limit + 1); i++) {
    adjacents[i] = {}
    for (let j = 0; j < potentialSquares.length; j++) {
      if (potentialSquares[j] > i) {
        const dif = potentialSquares[j] - i
        if (dif <= limit) {
          adjacents[i][dif] = 1
        } else {
          break
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return adjacents
}

function getPotentialSquares (limit) {
  const maxSum = limit * 2 - 1
  let square = 4
  let i = 3
  const potentialSquares = []
  while (square <= maxSum) {
    potentialSquares.push(square)
    square = i * i
    i++
  }
  return potentialSquares
}
```

At first I was using a hash table with an array of adjacent nodes on each key. But when my algorithm had to delete vertices from the object, it had to look for elements in arrays several times, which took linear time every time. I made the adjacent vertices hashable and that improved my execution time. Then I look for the path with this function:

```
function findSquarePathInRange (limit) {
  // Build  the graph object
  const adjacents = buildAdjacentsObject(limit)

  // Deep copy the object before making any changes
  const adjacentsCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(adjacents))

  // Create empty path
  const solution = []

  // Recursively complete the path
  function getSolution (currentCandidates) {
    if (solution.length === limit) {
      return solution
    }

    // Sort the candidate vertices to start with the ones with less adjacent vert
    currentCandidates = currentCandidates.sort((a, b) => {
      return Object.keys(adjacentsCopy[a]).length -
        Object.keys(adjacentsCopy[b]).length
    })

    for (const candidate of currentCandidates) {
      // Add the candidate to the path
      solution.push(candidate)

      // and delete it from the object
      for (const candidateAdjacent in adjacents[candidate]) {
        delete adjacentsCopy[candidateAdjacent][candidate]
      }
      if (getSolution(Object.keys(adjacentsCopy[candidate]))) {
        return solution
      }
      // If not solution was found, delete the element from the path
      solution.pop()

      // and add it back to the object
      for (const candidateAdjacent in adjacents[candidate]) {
        adjacentsCopy[candidateAdjacent][candidate] = 1
      }
    }
    return false
  }

  const endSolution = getSolution(
    Array.from(Array(limit).keys()).slice(1)
  )
  // The elements of the path can't be strings
  return (endSolution) ? endSolution.map(x => parseInt(x, 10)) : false
}
```

My solution works 'fast' but it's not fast enough. I need to pass more than 200 tests in less than 12 seconds and so far it's only passing 150. Probably both my algorithm and my usage of JS can be improved, so, my questions:

1. Can you see a bottleneck in the code? The sorting step should be the one taking more time but it also gets me to the solution faster. Also, I'm not sure if I'm using the best data structure for this kind of problem. I tried classic looping instead of using `for..in` and `for..of` but it didn't change the performance.
2. Do you see any place where I can save previous calculations to look for them later?

Regarding the last question, I read that there is a dynamic solution to the problem but everywhere I found one, it looks for minimum distance, number of paths or existence of path, not the path itself. I read this everywhere but I'm unable to apply it:

> Also, a dynamic programming algorithm of Bellman, Held, and Karp can be used to solve the problem in time O(n2 2n). In this method, one determines, for each set S of vertices and each vertex v in S, whether there is a path that covers exactly the vertices in S and ends at v. For each choice of S and v, a path exists for (S,v) if and only if v has a neighbor w such that a path exists for (S − v,w), which can be looked up from already-computed information in the dynamic program.

I just can't get the idea on how to implement that if I'm not looking for all the paths. I found [this](https://leetcode.com/articles/number-of-squareful-arrays/) implementation of a similar problem in python that uses a cache and some binary but again, I could translate it from py but I'm not sure how to apply those concepts to my algorithm.

I'm currently out of ideas so any hint of something to try would be super helpful.

**EDIT 1:**

After Photon comment, I tried going back to using a hash table for the graph, storing adjacent vertices as arrays. Also added a separate array of bools to keep track of the remaining vertices.

That improved my efficiency a lot. With these changes I avoided the need to convert object keys to arrays all the time, no need to copy the graph object as it was not going to be modified and no need to loop after adding one node to the path. The bad thing is that then I needed to check that separate object when sorting, to check which adjacent vertices were still available. Also, I had to filter the arrays before passing them to the next recursion.

Yosef approach from the first answer of using an array to store the adjacent vertices and access them by index prove even more efficient. My code so far (no changes to the square finding function):

```
function square_sums_row (limit) {
  const adjacents = buildAdjacentsObject(limit)
  const adjacentsCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(adjacents))
  const solution = []

  function getSolution (currentCandidates) {
    if (solution.length === limit) {
      return solution
    }

    currentCandidates = currentCandidates.sort((a, b) => {
      return adjacentsCopy[a].length - adjacentsCopy[b].length
    })
    for (const candidate of currentCandidates) {
      solution.push(candidate)
      for (const candidateAdjacent of adjacents[candidate]) {
        adjacentsCopy[candidateAdjacent] = adjacentsCopy[candidateAdjacent]
          .filter(t => t !== candidate)
      }
      if (getSolution(adjacentsCopy[candidate])) {
        return solution
      }
      solution.pop()
      for (const candidateAdjacent of adjacents[candidate]) {
        adjacentsCopy[candidateAdjacent].push(candidate)
      }
    }
    return false
  }
  return getSolution(Array.from(Array(limit + 1).keys()).slice(1))
}

function buildAdjacentsObject (limit) {
  const potentialSquares = getPotentialSquares(limit)
  const squaresLength = potentialSquares.length
  const adjacents = []
  for (let i = 1; i < (limit + 1); i++) {
    adjacents[i] = []
    for (let j = 0; j < squaresLength; j++) {
      if (potentialSquares[j] > i) {
        const dif = potentialSquares[j] - i
        if (dif <= limit) {
          adjacents[i].push(dif)
        } else {
          break
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return adjacents
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

The code performs fine in most of the cases, but my worst case scenarios suck:

```
// time for 51: 30138.229ms
// time for 77: 145214.155ms
// time for 182: 22964.025ms
```

**EDIT 3:**

I accepted Yosef answer as it was super useful to improve the efficiency of my JS code. Found a way to tweak the algorithm to avoid paths with dead ends using some of the restrictions from this paper [A Search Procedure for Hamilton Paths and Circuits.](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/321850.321854).

Basically, before calling another recursion, I check 2 things:

- If there is any node with no edges that's not part of the path till now and the path is missing more than 1 node
- If there were more than 2 nodes with 1 edge (one can be following node, that had 2 edges before deleting the edge to the current node, and other can be the last node)

Both situations make it impossible to find a Hamiltonian path with the remaining nodes and edges (if you draw the graph it'll be clear why). Following that logic, there's another improvement if you check nodes with only 2 edges (1 way to get in and other to go out). I think you can use that to delete other edges in advance but it was not necessary at least for me.

Now, the algorithm performs worse in most cases, where just sorting by remaining edges was good enough to predict the next node and extra work was added, but it's able to solve the worst cases in a much better time. For example, `limit = 77` it's solved in 15ms but `limit=1000` went from 30ms to 100ms.

This is a really long post, if you have any edit suggestions, let me know. I don't think posting the final code it's the best idea taking into account that you can't check the solutions in the platform before solving the kata. But the accepted answer and this final edit should be good advice to think about this last part while still learning something. Hope it's useful.

Comment: do you have some test data and the wanted result?

Comment: Instead of actually deleting vertices, just have an additional array or ES6 Set to keep track which vertices exist, all those data structure copies makes your algorithm slow

Comment: @NinaScholz I don't have access to the test code, but for example if limit=15, the result should be this array: [9,  7,  2, 14, 11,  5, 4, 12, 13,  3,  6, 10, 15,  1,  8].

Comment: @huancito, thank you. please add this to the question.

Comment: @Photon you mean that every time I delete a node property I copy the data structure? I'm only deep copying the data structure once before calling the recursive function and then I modify the same object all the time

Comment: @Photon My first approach was having the remaining vertices in a different array but then I had to filter the adjacent vertices before passing that result to the recursive function. The filter then had to check if every element still existed with indexOf and I figured out that was more expensive. Also, if I keep a separate object, then the sorting will also be more complex. But in all this cases I was using arrays of the actual values, maybe I could try using the array keys as values and store bools. I will try that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By replacing the object by an array you save yourself from convert the object to an array every time you want to find the length (which you do a lot - in any step of the sort algorithm), or when you want to get the keys for the next candidates. in my tests the code below has been a **lot**  more effective in terms of execution time
(`0.102s` vs `1.078s` for `limit=4500` on my machine)

```js
function buildAdjacentsObject (limit) {
        const potentialSquares = getPotentialSquares(limit)
        const adjacents = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < (limit + 1); i++) {
            adjacents[i] = [];
            for (let j = 0; j < potentialSquares.length; j++) {
                if (potentialSquares[j] > i) {
                    const dif = potentialSquares[j] - i
                    if (dif <= limit) {
                        adjacents[i].push(dif)
                    } else {
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return adjacents
    }
    function getPotentialSquares (limit) {
        const maxSum = limit * 2 - 1
        let square = 4
        let i = 3
        const potentialSquares = []
        while (square <= maxSum) {
            potentialSquares.push(square)
            square = i * i
            i++
        }
        return potentialSquares
    }
    function findSquarePathInRange (limit) {
        // Build  the graph object
        const adjacents = buildAdjacentsObject(limit)

        // Deep copy the object before making any changes
        const adjacentsCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(adjacents))

        // Create empty path
        const solution = [];

        // Recursively complete the path
        function getSolution (currentCandidates) {
            if (solution.length === limit) {
                return solution
            }

            // Sort the candidate vertices to start with the ones with less adjacent vert
            currentCandidates = currentCandidates.sort((a, b) => {
                return adjacentsCopy[a].length - adjacentsCopy[b].length
            });
            for (const candidate of currentCandidates) {
                // Add the candidate to the path
                solution.push(candidate)

                // and delete it from the object
                for (const candidateAdjacent of adjacents[candidate]) {
                    adjacentsCopy[candidateAdjacent] = adjacentsCopy[candidateAdjacent].filter(t=>t!== candidate)
                }
                if (getSolution(adjacentsCopy[candidate])) {
                    return solution
                }
                // If not solution was found, delete the element from the path
                solution.pop()

                // and add it back to the object
                for (const candidateAdjacent of adjacents[candidate]) {
                    adjacentsCopy[candidateAdjacent].push(candidate);
                }
            }
            return false
        }

        const endSolution = getSolution(
            Array.from(Array(limit).keys()).slice(1)
        )
        // The elements of the path can't be strings
        return endSolution
    }
    var t = new Date().getTime();
    var res = findSquarePathInRange(4500);
    var t2 = new Date().getTime();
    console.log(res, ((t2-t)/1000).toFixed(4)+'s');
```

Comment: Thanks Yosef! After Photon comment to my question, I changed my data structure to store the adjacent vertices as arrays and tried using a separate array of bools to keep the state of remaining vertices to visit and cut execution time by half. But your approach proved even more efficient. However, the kata seems to be even more difficult, as I'm passing now almost 400 tests but not all. CodeWars does not tell me the remaining tests to pass. Any other idea? If I don't get any better answer I will accept yours as my algorithm is already much better. Thank you!

Comment: One thing I don't get from your code. When you add back an item, you do this in a loop: adjacentsCopy[candidateAdjacent] = candidate. It seems to me that you are replacing a list for a single element, however your code does not break. In my version I'm doing adjacentsCopy[candidateAdjacent].push(candidate) instead

Comment: you say before you have to pass 200 tests... anyway, maybe there is some big number for `limit`, and it is execute the maximun number of function recalls, so you get `call stack error`. try to reshape it to a loop instead of recursion

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. The kata said in the description that there were more than 200 tests but now I found the author saying in a comment that he changed it to 1000 tests (just 4 days ago). I did not specify in my question but the max limit is 1000 so there's no error there. Just have to pass 1000 tests in 12 seconds, which is the platform limit. I will edit my question. Thanks for your answers!

Comment: I don't pass in time. My code is tested 1000 times with random numbers in the range 2.. 1000. Depending on the numbers I get, I'm passing between 250 and 650 tests. I guess some numbers in the range are trickier. If I ran my code for all the numbers in the range it takes about 212 s. If I try to get the solution for limit=1000, 1000 times, it only takes 4 seconds. I'm not sure if the base algorithm will be suitable for the task. What do you think?

Comment: I ran a test to find the worst numbers. { 77: 145s, 51: 30s, 182: 23s }. I confirmed this values individually. There are others between 200 and 400 ms, but I should pass with some of those. If I get 77, 51 or 182 in a random test, the code won't pass.

Comment: Well, solved it changing a bit the algorithm, but your answer helped a lot. Thank you again.